# What is the lowest and highest possible pseudo-range?

Tags: gps, post-processing

I am trying to compact the required data that needs to be sent to the server to post-process the receiver's position. To do this, I figured it'd be possible to offset the pseudo-range by a fixed value. This would decrease the actual value that needs to be transmitted. The idea behind this is that the satellite is always a few thousand kilometers away, no matter where it is in the world.

The pseudo-range is transmitted as a double, which is 64 bits long. For my application, every byte I don't need to send should be scraped. It seems to me that a 5-byte unsigned value should be enough to store the pseudo-range offset. It allows me to adjust the pseudo-range by 1100 km in mm precision. Possibly a 32-bit floating point value would suffice, even.

I have the freedom to use my own format for storing the pseudo-range value, as long as it requires less than 8 bytes.

Therefore I need to know, what is the range of the pseudo-range values one can receive?

Answer (score 1):

GPS PR measurements are between 60 mili-seconds to 92 mili-seconds.
Multiply by the speed of light to get the distance limits in meters.
Please note that this limits refers to GPS satellites only,
And take some safety margins..